# How to resize the stage inside of my window using Libgdx

Tags: java, screen, libgdx

I am trying to "resize" my game view within the screen using Libgdx. Indeed I need to let a black bar on the bottom and the left side of the screen. So as if you resize a square using your MS Paint or Gimp, I would like to do so with my game stage. (I've tried to upload a figure to set my issue clearer but apparently Stackoverflow forbids it for me)

I think I am mixing things up with Stage size, the Camera size and the Viewport. Any advice would be greatly appreciated !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using stage then you can try to replace camera view your own with other viewport dimensions.

```
Camera newCamera = new OrthographicCamera(300, 200);
//... here is some other camera initialization code
newCamera.update();//recalculate camera matrices
stage.setCamera(newCamera);

//after that you may need to update sprite batch projection matrix

_gameStage.getSpriteBatch().setProjectionMatrix(newCamera.combined);
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I am still getting trouble with your method though. The view is only shifted (and so cropped) on the top side of the screen. Maybe it is bound to the fact that I am using an OrthographicCamera ?

Comment: My bad, the problem was that I forgot to call the setToOrtho method. Now it works properly, thank you !